# Ignoring AWS plugin configuration file for Jetbrains IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gitignore

Jetbrains IntelliJ AWS Plugin generates AWS.xml file in the .idea folder
Would recommend adding it to .gitignore as these are user specific files.

Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project version="4">
      <component name="accountSettings">
        <option name="activeProfile" value="profile:dev" />
        <option name="activeRegion" value="us-west-2" />
        <option name="recentlyUsedProfiles">
          <list>
            <option value="profile:dev" />
          </list>
        </option>
        <option name="recentlyUsedRegions">
          <list>
            <option value="us-west-2" />
          </list>
        </option>
      </component>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the file contains user specific data, you should consider excluding it from the version control. See [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839) for details.

I would also recommend submitting a pull request to add this file by default to [JetBrains.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore).

Comment: well this post is for the pull request submitted. Need votes/comments/any qs for the same - https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/3326#issuecomment-599781420.